# Is using strings as keys for reference to other tables bad in terms of memory usage?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

So i have to deal with the following scenario:

I have a table , **users** , which holds all of the users of my application .
Each user has an email which is unique and thus could be the primary key of said table .

Let's now say i have a second table that associates some data with a user . What pops into my mind is to have that second table hold an **email** column which i can then use to associate a row with a user .Is this approach bad in terms of memory? Will MySQL store said email repeatedly for each extra table that holds an email column to reference **users** table? Should i instead just use an auto-increment id for each user and use that for the whole reference thing since an integer is way lighter than a string big enough to hold an email?

Comment: Memory use would be rather low on my list of concerns about using `email` as the primary key.  I'd be much more concerned about what happens when some user wants to update their email address.  Sure, you could define all your tables to have `on update cascade` foreign keys but that gets rather expensive when you have things like audit and log tables.  And that tends to be one of those test cases that gets overlooked when you're adding new tables where you might have set the foreign key up incorrectly.

Comment: "*Each user has an email which is unique and thus could be the primary key of said table.*" Primary keys must be unique *and* unchanging. If a user wants to change their email address you've got a problem. Also, to be "unique" emails must be normalized. FOO@EXAMPLE.COM is the same email as foo@example.com, but they are different strings.

Comment: @Schwern they are not though. Some email providers might treat them as the same, but it's not a given (similar case with `+` and `.`). Only the domain part is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes MySql and all other rdms will store the complete email as varchar and reserve space for the number of bytes it needs or the maximal size depending on the rdms.

Integer with up to 8 bytes for a big integer will only use these bytes, and are so faster when referencing.

In terms of speed you use  INTEGER, and consider other like varchar(36) for uuids when the need arises, for example different servers have to save data in the same table.

with emails a unique and so be indexed for referencing, you should take the extra mile and use Integer if you expect you will have big tables.

Answer (score 6):

If there is one `email` per `user`, add a column to the `users` table.

In general 1:1 mappings are not a good idea between tables; simply combine the tables.

UUIDs are a bad idea (for multiple reasons) unless you must generate unique identifiers in some *distributed* way.

A `VARCHAR` is not necessarily 'bad'; it may even save space over adding an otherwise unnecessary auto_increment.

A pet peeve is when someone uses a 4-byte INT (auto_increment) for `country_code` instead of a standard 2-letter country_code.

Comment: Could you expand on why UUIDs are a bad idea?

Comment: @Schwern Fragmentation of index, page splits during inserts, cache/page locality (relative to other data queried at the same time). A surrogate key is best if it is monotonically increasing, which is why auto increment is good and random is bad. Obviously if a natural key is likely to be queried that can be good as an index even if it is random.

Comment: And more:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Comment: @RickJames This seems to be mostly about storing it as varchar(36) which is a silly MySQLism. "*With these new features in MySQL 8.0.0 (Sep. 2016; 8.0.11 GA in Apr. 2018), this blog is rendered mostly useless... The UUID stored as a VARBINARY(16) can be indexed using functional indexes.*".

Comment: @Charlieface To be clear, are we talking about varchar(36) UUIDs or varbinary(16) UUIDs? And specific to MySQL or in general? For example, [Postgres has a UUID type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html).

Comment: @Schwern I was actually thinking more on the lines of a real `uniqueidentifier` type like in SQL Server, which is essentially a `binary(16)`, ultimately it's just a big random binary number. The notion of `varchar(36)` didn't even enter my head: as you say, wasn't aware anyone would be stupid enough to do that. And that document that Rick James links does actually mention the page-split problem.

Comment: @Schwern Picture the last page of a B+ tree. as you fill it, it is trivial to pack the previous node and get dense leaf utilization. That is good for locality, but not good for concurrency - everyone may want to insert in one page at the same time. When UUID is scattering the inserts all over the place, it makes it leave a lot of half full B+ tree pages around, but allows concurrent insert to happen more easily. It can also be used to distribute it into multiple servers, so each server has a 1/N chance of even having to do an insert.

Comment: @doug65536 - There is some of what you are saying.  However InnoDB and auto_increment are well optimized to minimize the contention from multiple clients adding at the "end".  For a mid-sized table, sure, the scattered inserts may be slightly faster.  For huge tables, and UUIDs (or other hashes), then I/O due to cache misses becomes a serious slowdown.

Comment: @doug65536 - And, for random inserts, the blocks settle down to about 69% full on average.  (100% drops to 2 blocks with 50%; then they gradually grow back to 100%.)

Comment: I don't agree with UUID keys either. I am just explaining why a person would use it. The cache hit spam of contending on the end of the table is really appealing, yes.

Comment: If you split a node in a B+ tree, you leave two half full ones behind. Not sure why you are pushing back on "half full". On average, yeah, they aren't all the worst case, but with uuid scattering it, you could well end up with very many completely pathological nodes that were full and had one leaf inserted, leaving it as two half full nodes. No?

Comment: If it were using auto-increment, it would be able to use subsequent adjacent inserts to pack it tight. It can hardly do that with uuids inserting randomly. Basically adds up to one to your B+ tree depth if your nodes are half full.

Comment: InnoDB combines two adjacent blocks that are less than half full, but does not bother with other less-than-full cases.